# Google Places Details search System.err

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm attempting to locate a restaurant by name using an AutoCompleteTextView which successfully obtains the places id. I've also checked the http request manually in my browser which responds with the correct information. When this code is executed, a system.err is shown in the LogCat console in Eclipse. My code below;

```
public class AdvancedSearch extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "com.lw276.justdine";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    // ------------ make your specific key ------------
    private static final String API_KEY = "MyAPIKEY";

    private Activity context = this;
    static HashMap<String, String> place;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_search);
        final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        Button btnAdvancedSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advanced_search_btn);
        btnAdvancedSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = autoCompView.getText().toString();
                if(place.containsKey(str)){
                    String placeId = place.get(str);
                    Log.d("advancedSearchBtn: placeId = ", placeId);
                    Log.i("advancedSearchBtn", "Search button has been pressed");
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, GoogleMap.class);
                    i.putExtra("advancedSearch", placeId);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please select an item from the autocomplete list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
//      String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
//      Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                    + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            place = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "description"));
                    System.out
                            .println("============================================================");
                    resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "description"));

                 String description = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                 String placeId = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id");
                 place.put( description, placeId);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
            implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context,
                int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

//      @Override
//      public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int index) {
//         return resultList.get(index);
//      }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index){
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

The googlePlaces example =

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJCSWGvY-FdUgRpGdg10FTIIg&key="MY_API_KEY"
```

Is it obvious to anyone why no markers are being placed on my map fragment?

Errors from LogCat:
http://pastebin.com/T1AFbw3s

Google Maps and Markers class:
http://pastebin.com/hT2XwuE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because I was using the same code to add markers onto the Map, when the detail search was used to identify a single place, the JSONArray type was incompatible with the result set... If that makes sense.
I had to separate the two by checking if a nearby search was being performed or a details search. Below was the code for the details search only:

```
resultObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("result"); // <---
                    places = new MarkerOptions[1];
                    LatLng placeLL = null;
                    String placeName = "";
                    String vicinity = "";
                    try {
                        JSONObject placeObject = resultObject;
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject(
                                "geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                        placeLL = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(loc
                                .getString("lat")), Double.valueOf(loc
                                .getString("lng")));
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    } catch (JSONException jse) {
                        missingValue = true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (missingValue){
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        places[0] = new MarkerOptions().position(placeLL)
                                .title(placeName).snippet(vicinity);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The error you are having is due to parsing the Json incorrectly at line 193 of `GoogleMap` activity:

   ```
      JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
   ```

I believe the key is `result` instead of `results`.
I can give you a better explanation if I could see the json response. Meanwhile,
I would also suggest you to use `Gson` Library to parse the json responses to objects instead of mapping them manually. It would be alot easier.

2. `Markers` need to be added manually:

   ```
   private void addMarker(String name, double lat, double long){
      LatLng latlong = LatLng.newInstance(lat, long);
      MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
      markerOptions.setIcon(Icon.newInstance("/img/icon.png"));
      markerOptions.setTitle(name);  
      Marker marker = new Marker(latlong, markerOptions);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
   }
   ```

Comment: I've added the System.err logs and also the java class dealing with Maps and markers as links to PasteBin.

Comment: I've made the change to the GoogleMap activity but it doesn't give me any results for either the details search, or a nearby search
EDIT:
However, I have double checked the Log and you are right that it seems to be the lack of result set